# Recent minor upgrade on 22.04.1 results in breaking QEMU binaries for gemu-kvm

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, kvm-virtualization

Prior to a recent minor upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.1, I had a working qemu-kvm virtual machine. I have Windows 10 installed in Virtual Machine Manager. After the upgrade, I get errors when trying to start the virtual machine. I tried checking `libvirtd`, and got these errors when executing `$ sudo systemctl status libvirtd`:

```
Cannot check QEMU binary /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: No such file or directory
internal error: Failed to parse snapshot XML from file '/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/snapshot/Win10/Win10.xml'
Cannot check QEMU binary /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm: No such file or directory
invalid argument: could not find capabilities for arch=x86_64 domaintype=qemu
internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64
```

Some search results on this problem suggested making a softlink to `/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm`, but that file does not exist, even after reinstalling `qemu-kvm`.

From some answers, it sounds like there were some names of files were changed, but I cannot find anything that will fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mention "*minor upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.1*" which was back in 2022 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded a week+ before that date), which isn't recent. A updated 22.04 system currently reports itself as 22.04.3 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/) so are you sure of facts? or is August 2022 recent?   FYI:  *Some packages versions show as 22.04 when not upgraded, and 22.04.1 when upgraded (to any level) but that's not a indication of what you're running*

Comment: Good point. I was looking at the results of uname -a. When I did lsb_release -a, it shows I am using 22.04.3. I also backhandedly resolved the problem. In reponse to your comment, I did `apt update` again, and noticed that one of the packages key was invalid. I don't have the error anymore (I had to reboot afwerward), but when I added the key for `home_vtrefny.gpg` and updated/upgraded, and then rebooted, the problem went away.

I am not even sure what package was not upgraded, but evidently it was what was missing.

Comment: Well done for solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was checking the result of `apt-update`. It turns out that the key `home_vtrefny.gpg` was out of date or missing after the upgrade. When I downloaded that key, and did an `apt-update; apt-upgrade`, and then rebooted, the problem was resolved.